# Counting orders by supplier results in SQL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to get how many orders each supplier have, by showing two columns, CompanyName and number of orders. And then Sorting them by descending order.

My SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sp.CompanyName), COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)
FROM Suppliers AS sp
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON sp.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS od ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
                                 AND o.OrderID = od.OrderID
ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC
```

But I get the following errors:

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 65
> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
> Column 'Suppliers.CompanyName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My tables:

[image]

Comment: The error tells you exactly how to fix it, add the missing item to your ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I believe you also need to add a `GROUP BY (sp.CompanyName)`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to count the number of orders per company.  If so there is no date to order by.

Comment: @MintBerryCRUNCH I've tried that, and I still get an error. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 70
The multi-part identifier "od.OrderID" could not be bound.

Comment: @MintBerryCRUNCH SELECT DISTINCT(sp.CompanyName), COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)
FROM Suppliers as sp
INNER JOIN Products as p
ON sp.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
INNER JOIN Orders as o
ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] as od
ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
AND 
o.OrderID=od.OrderID
-- ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC
GROUP BY sp.CompanyName;

Comment: That doesn't logically make sense, you can't order by something you are aggregating... what would it even mean?

Comment: You need to explain and show what your desired results are so we can help you accomplish it... because as written literally isn't possible.

Comment: @Mia Larsen why are you trying to `ORDER BY o.OrderDate`?

Comment: Ignore the orderdate, and focus on the actual issue, I think the ordering by date is just an error, since it should be ordered by the COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID) instead, according to the text.

Comment: Are trying to get the number of orders per company? If so remove the `ORDER BY o.OrderDate` and add in a `GROUP BY (sp.CompanyName)`. If that is not the result you a looking for please can you show what you would like the desired result to be.

Comment: @andrelange91 ups my mistake your right.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it works on the whole resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be the correct one as mentioned in the comments in the post.

```
SELECT sp.CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID) as orders
FROM Suppliers as sp
INNER JOIN Products as p
ON sp.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] as od
INNER JOIN Orders as o
ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
AND 
o.OrderID=od.OrderID
GROUP BY sp.CompanyName;
```

Comment: Might be right there ^^ Updated my answer.